# How to create a FILE in Desktop, using c

Tags: c, windows, file, desktop

How,and what libs I need to create and manipulate a FILE in the Desktop? using only C, not C# or C++. 
I'm using Codeblocks, I using allegro, what means I can´t use windows.h lib, The program need to work in windows.

Comment: That depends... Did you want to use the Windows API (`CreateFile()`), the POSIX-ish API (`_open()` or `_sopen_s()`), or ISO standard C (`fopen()`)? Of course, there are third-party libraries you might use as well, such as GLib, though you likely don't have them installed in a place where your compiler can find them by default, if they're installed at all.

Comment: I want to use the fopen, and I can´t use the lib windows.h why I'm using allegro in the program.

Comment: You can't write a Windows program without windows libraries and header files. Or you need cross-platform solution. Use `allegro` tag to ask question about allegro.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Vista or higher, use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to find he path for desktop. You have to use Unicode functions to get the file path, use `_wfopen_s`. You can write ANSI to the file, but it is recommended to write UTF16 or to convert text to UTF8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t *desktop;
    if(S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &desktop))
    {
        wprintf(L"Desktop path: %s\n", desktop);

        wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
        swprintf_s(filename, MAX_PATH, L"%s\\%s", desktop, L"file.txt");
        wprintf(L"Filename path: %s\n", filename);

        FILE *fp;
        _wfopen_s(&fp, filename, L"w");
        if(fp)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "Hello world\n");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"can't create file\n");
        }

        CoTaskMemFree(desktop);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In Windows XP use `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` (deprecated)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t desktop[MAX_PATH];
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, desktop)))
    {
        wprintf(L"desktop: %s\n", desktop);
        wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];
        swprintf(path, L"%s\\%s", desktop, L"filename.txt");

        HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(path, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            DWORD temp;
            const char *buf = "hello world";
            WriteFile(handle, buf, strlen(buf), &temp, NULL);
            CloseHandle(handle);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("can't create file\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when I compilate your program, appers FOLDERID_Desktop undeclarete.

Comment: @DavidAmatoMantegari On MinGW targets, you should find it in the `knownfolders.h` header file that is automatically included with one of `Windows.h` or `Shlobj.h` above. For `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to work, I had to `#include <sdkddkver.h>` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` before any other includes and add `-lole32` and `-luuid` to the end of my compilation line to link the necessary libraries for the symbols to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are on Windows, you'd want to look at [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) and its associated functions.

The lifecycle of a file is as follows: You can create it (or, if it exists, open it) using `CreateFile`, and once it is created/opened, you can use the resulting *file handle* to manipulate it with [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx), [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx), and potentially [`DeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx). Once you're done, you need to close the handle with [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1 If you are using Unix or Unix-like system, you can call

```
system("touch ~/Desktop/FILE");
```

in your code, and you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

This calls the command "touch ~/Desktop/FILE". If you want to handle (read/write) the file after this, you have to call `fopen` with correct mode. But the 2nd method is much better if you want to write something into the file.

2 You can also use

For Unix or Unix-like operating systems:
`FILE *file = fopen("~/Desktop/FILE", "w+")`

For Windows:
`FILE *file = fopen("C:\\Users\\YOUR_USER_NAME\\Desktop\\FILE", "w+")`
(*Assumes you are using the default user folder location.)

This creates the file, and then you can read/write to the file after this. Be sure to used the correct mode. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) is a reference for `fopen` and modes. Remember to `#include <stdlib.h>`.